# checking input against tuple of responses

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code that check if the input matches a tuple of inputs

```
if name1 in confirms:
```

And here's the tuple

```
confirms = ('yes', 'yeah', 'yea' )
```

But how do I make it so if something like 'yes I do' or 'yeah of course' is entered. It understands that Yeah is in the input and deals with it the same as just saying 'yeah'

Comment: How? By writing some code. You can tell that 'yeah' or 'yes' is the first word, so simply checking the first word would work, no? Oh, but what if someone types `YES I DO`, what then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would would do something like this, lower casing the input to test :

```
[x.lower() in conf for x in name1.split()]
```

then just test if True is in this new list by using the [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function

```
any([x.lower() in conf for x in input.split()])
```

This has several draw backs, for instance if the user wrote a positive and a negative this would find the positive. I would maybe look into a different approach to your initial problem.

Comment: I store the name and it outputs once but then gets buggy?                                                                 print ('Hi %s') % (name)                                      locat = raw_input("Where are you from %s ?").lower() % (name)                                         It says 'Where are you from %s ?' Instead of saying the name?

Comment: that is a separate question! but i'm feeling nice. the syntax needs to be `locat = raw_input("Where are you from %s ?" % (name)).lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to check that the lowercased version of the first word in the reply is within the list:

```
confirms = ('yes', 'yeah', 'yea')
if (name1.split() or ('',))[0].lower() in confirms:
  print 'YES'
else:
  print 'NO'
```